# How to integrate trading view into electron

Tags: javascript, charts, electron, desktop-application, tradingview-api

I wanted to build trading apps using *electron* JS and using the TradingView library but I got stuck on how to implement it. I also created a new blank project to implement it, but still result.

**Is there anyone has ever implement TradingView to electron and could give me solution to this?**

[Blank app result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOkNu.png)

[image]

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vCYp.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://demo_chart.tradingview.com/charting_library/charting_library.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://demo_chart.tradingview.com/datafeeds/udf/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://demo_chart.tradingview.com/datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
     results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
   }

   TradingView.onready(function()
   {
    var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
     // debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
     fullscreen: true,
     symbol: 'AAPL',
     interval: 'D',
     container_id: "tv_chart_container",

     // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
     datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("https://demo_feed.tradingview.com"),
     library_path: "charting_library/",
     locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",

     disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
     enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
     charts_storage_url: 'http://saveload.tradingview.com',
     charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
     client_id: 'tradingview.com',
     user_id: 'public_user_id',
     theme: getParameterByName('theme'),
    });
   });

  </script>

 </head>

 <body style="margin:0px;">
  <div id="tv_chart_container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: It look like you have a permission problem too. Check R/W permission on your files and directories, and make sure you're not trying cross site calls when using the libraries.

Comment: Have you solved this? I faced exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Never used electron so using this opportunity to try it out myself. This is the steps I took.

Look at the documentation https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

1) created a folder called electron-test

2) run command npm init in that folder

3) modify package.json to be this

```
{
  "name": "electron-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

4) create main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

5) create index.html

6) run command npm install electron

7) run command npm start

This is the result

[image]

Comment: That's not what I mean, I wanted to implement tradingview into electron

Comment: You have to apply here https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/. You will get the library and may need to ask for the documentation. Just can't copy their html and change the src.

Comment: I have applied it, got the library but there are some error in implementing the library

Comment: You have the library but you are not using it in your code.

Comment: @mysteryfollow What do you mean "my own library"?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyone has ever implement TradingView to electron and could give me solution to this?

Well I don't have solution to the error, but I have found my way out to build an tradingView+ElectronJs app.

In short, you can start with [TradingView Charting Library Integration Examples](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples), from which you can choose the kind of integration template to start with(I just use react-javascript to start my app).And I just take this template for example.

After follow [How to start](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/tree/master/react-javascript#how-to-start) to configure the app properly. You should first install election to your app(which means run `npm install --save electron` in the directory root), then add the main.js to your directory root, and configure your package.json and main.js properly. Blow is my package.json and main.js code.

#### package.json

```
{
"name": "knownsec-fed",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"main": "main.js", // 配置启动文件
"homepage":".", // 
"dependencies": {
  "electron": "^1.7.10",
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "electron-start": "electron ." // start electron app
}
```

}

#### main.js

```
    const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
    const path = require('path')
    const url = require('url')

    let mainWindow

    function createWindow () {

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

      /**
        mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
          pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
          protocol: 'file:',
          slashes: true
        }))
      */

      mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/');


      // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()


      mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
      })
    }

    app.on('ready', createWindow)

    app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
      if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })

    app.on('activate', function () {
      if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
      }
    })
```

to start the electron app, first run `npm start` to start react then run `npm run electron-start` to start electron app and then all thing done.

Answer (score -1):

When you open Object with widget, your widget trying to find static folder from wrong path. Just connect library in widget option like this:

[image: pic of my code]